# Using ng-repeat and setting ng-model as the property of an object

Tags: angularjs

I have an object that looks somewhat like this(cleaned it up for this question):

```
group: {
  object1: {
   row_id: 1  
  },
  object2: {
   row_id: 2
  }
 };
```

This is what my html looks like:

```
<li ng-repeat="object in group">
  Row number {{object.row_id}}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="object.row_id">
</li>
```

This is a very rudimentary version of what I'm working on currently. My problem is that angular is not evaluating ng-model to anything other than object.row_id, where it should be equal to the property in the object. For simplicity I did not add the controller declaration(ng-controller) to make it easier to read and find the issue. The row number is showing when evaluated with {{}} outside of ng-model.

Hope we can solve this!

Comment: You group is not an array, whereas your ng-repeat expression is for array.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue. So I would have to put a second ng-repeat to loop over key, value to have the desired ng-model, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the object hash for repeat the syntax is

```
<li ng-repeat="(k,v) in group">
  Row number {{v.row_id}}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="v.row_id">
</li>
```

Comment: `v` can be used instead of `group[k]` inside the loop. It's clearer and faster.

Comment: Looks great. I changed everything in my source code and it all still works. However, the ng-model is still resulting in v.row_id instead of the actualy id in the object hash.